# Select/unselect checkbox in re-frame

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I'm adding a search id element to my **app-db** with:

```
[:input {:type "checkbox" :on-change #(reframe/dispatch [:add-elm {:subject_id subject-id}])}]
```

but I don't know how to recognize when the final user is checking or unchecking the box in order to put or withdraw the element from app-db. I want to avoid searching in the app-db to see if the element is already there.

Comment: why would you want to avoid that? 
That's a pretty good usecase for a subscription

Comment: you could also look at the fork form library who makes it a lot easier to deal with forms

Answer (score 0):

1) Add an ID to the checkbox:

```
   [:input {:type "checkbox" :title (:subject row-subject) 
          :id (str "subjects_" (:id row-subject))
          :on-change #(rf/dispatch [:add-search-elm {"subjects" (:id row-subject)}])}]
```

2) Get and read the DOM element:

```
 (let [ksection  (first (first updates))  ;; key subject
      vsection  (get updates ksection)   ;; value subject
      elm       (str ksection "_" vsection)
      checkbox  (gdom/getElement elm)
      checked   (.. checkbox -checked)]
     (.log js/console (str ">>> ksection >>>>> " ksection  ";;  vsection >> " vsection  ";;  elm >> " elm "   checkbox >>> " checkbox ";; checked >> " checked))
```